# Correct way to add 22 to 4 to get 26

Tags: logical-deduction, calculation-puzzle

Inspired by five other puzzles, how could it be possible that in base $\pi$ adding 22 to 4 gives 26? What is the correct way to do it?

Unlike all of the other puzzles, consider these numbers in base $\pi$.

Comment: Could you define base $\pi$? Or is this supposed to be a lateral thinking puzzle?

Comment: not different from any other base.

Comment: for an $n$-digit number, $\sum_0^{n-1} (d_i \times\ pi^i)$

Comment: Then would you define $9_\pi = 9_{10}$ and $10_\pi = \pi_{10}$? If so, then how would you represent $10_{10}$ in base $\pi$?

Comment: How would you represent $\pi$ in base 10? In a conventional sense, one can't, since $\pi$ is irrational.  Same answer for your question.

Comment: Very true. This is what happens when I'm up late :p

Comment: I suppose one could extend the symbol-set of a base-$\pi$ system, ala hexadecimal, to let multi symbol base-10 numbers such as $10$ be represented by a letter, say $A$, in which case the answer to your question would be $A_\pi$

Comment: This is not a puzzling question - it is a mathematics question.

Comment: Um, $4$ and $26$ are not valid base $\pi$ numbers as they contain "pigits"(?) greater than $3$

Comment: You're mistaken. They're valid. They're just not in "standard form".

Comment: So A is a valid base ten number and 2 is a valid binary number? How so? FYI you should have addressed your comment to me using @JonathanAllan so I would have received a notification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding $2x + 2$ to $4$ gets us $2x + 6$, regardless of which base (value of $x$) we're otherwise working in. And because $\pi$ is an irrational number, this form is the simplest form you're going to get.

So straight addition definitely works.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps:

> $22_\pi + 4_\pi = 2\pi_{10} + 2_{10} + 4_{10} = 2\pi_{10} + 6_{10} = 26_{\pi} $

Comment: this is the same answer that joe Z gave

Comment: I posted mine before his, but his was accepted. @Jasen

Comment: the timing is not clear on the web site, I am not accusing you of copying.

Comment: @Jasen Don't worry about it :p